# Python xlsxwriter: Adjust excel reference cells in loop when creating formula

Tags: python-2.7, formula, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to include a formula column in an excel spreadsheet written in a loop.  However, the formula is copying to each of the cells exactly the same.

The script below will produce the formula =IF(E2>0,(G2+H2)/E2,0) for all the cells. Is there a way to get it to update each row so that, for example, in row 16 the column will read =IF(E16>0,(G16+H16)/E16,0)?

```py
for iRow, stVa in enumerate(dLocP):

    stVb,stVc,stVd = dLocP[stVa]

    Cworksheet.write(iRow + 1,0,stVa)
    Cworksheet.write(iRow + 1,1,stVb)
    Cworksheet.write(iRow + 1,2,stVc)
    Cworksheet.write(iRow + 1,3,stVd)
    Cworksheet.write_formula(iRow + 1, 4, '=IF(E2>0,(G2+H2)/E2,0)')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XlsxWriter has some functions for [creating cell references](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-utility-functions):

```
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

cell = xl_rowcol_to_cell(1, 2)  # C2
```

However, in this case it would probably be easier just to do simple string formatting:

```
for row_num in range(4):
    formula = '=IF(E%d>0,(G%d+H%d)/E%d,0)' % tuple([row_num + 1] * 4)
```

Or with new style format():

```
for row_num in range(4):
    formula = '=IF(E{}>0,(G{}+H{})/E{},0)'.format(*([row_num + 1] * 4))
```

In either case the output would look like this:

```
=IF(E1>0,(G1+H1)/E1,0)
=IF(E2>0,(G2+H2)/E2,0)
=IF(E3>0,(G3+H3)/E3,0)
=IF(E4>0,(G4+H4)/E4,0)
```

Update: Added working example like original above:

```
for iRow, stVa in enumerate(dLocP):

    stVb,stVc,stVd = dLocP[stVa]

    Cworksheet.write(iRow + 1,0,stVa)
    Cworksheet.write(iRow + 1,1,stVb)
    Cworksheet.write(iRow + 1,2,stVc)
    Cworksheet.write(iRow + 1,3,stVd)

    formula = '=IF(E{}>0,(G{}+H{})/E{},0)'.format(*([iRow + 2] * 4))
    Cworksheet.write_formula(iRow + 1, 4, formula)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still new to Python and I'm having trouble figuring out where the loop should be placed. I'm trying to use the option you gave with format(). However, after it runs all the rows say. =IF(E4>0,(G4+H4)/E4,0). Should it be placed inside the original loop or outside the original loop?

Comment: Thank you. The working example worked perfectly and did produce the desired result:                                                 =IF(E1>0,(G1+H1)/E1,0)
=IF(E2>0,(G2+H2)/E2,0)
=IF(E3>0,(G3+H3)/E3,0)
=IF(E4>0,(G4+H4)/E4,0)